# Why is the message sent to the client after the loop process is complete?

Tags: php, for-loop, ratchet

I have a problem, why are messages sent to the client sent after the looping process is finished even though every process and before the process I added the function `send();` to send a message to the client but the message is received by the client after the looping process is complete, here is the code

1. how to send message to client with `send();` function in realtime and no need to wait for the loop process to finish ?

```php
public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
        $data = json_decode($msg, true);
    
        if ($data['type'] === 'file') { 
           
        require ('../../conn.php'); 
        $fileName = $data['name'];          
        $username = $data['username']; 
        $usernameMD5 = md5($username);
        $path = $this->uploadsPath.$usernameMD5. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$fileName;        
        $from->send("File '{$fileName}' uploaded and processed.");
        flush();
       
        //cek file
        if (!file_exists($path)) {
            $from->send("File '{$fileName}' not found.");
            return;
          }         
          
          //mulai proses
          $spreadsheet = IOFactory::load($path);
          $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
          $total_rows = $sheet->getHighestRow() - 1;  

          
          for ($i = 2; $i <= $sheet->getHighestRow(); $i++) { 
            if ($i > $total_rows) {
                $from->send("Processed all rows.");             
                break;
            }
            $from->send("Processed row $i"); // kirim pesan ke client
            flush();       

 
          }          

        }
}
```

Please help so I can send messages to the client server while it is looping, in the code above I use ratchet as a websocket.
Thank You

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Also, be warned that your database queries are highly vulnerable for SQL injection. Have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Comment: I'm stuck on the part of sending a message to the client using the function $from->send("Processed row $i"); The message is sent to the client after the loop process is complete

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: thank you I have given the clarification

Answer (score 0):

you can use a technique called batching. Instead of sending a message to the client every time a row is processed, you can accumulate the messages in a buffer and send them in batches at regular intervals or when the buffer reaches a certain size.

```
public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
    $data = json_decode($msg, true);

    if ($data['type'] === 'file') { 

        require ('../../conn.php'); 
        $fileName = $data['name'];          
        $username = $data['username']; 
        $usernameMD5 = md5($username);
        $path = $this->uploadsPath.$usernameMD5. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$fileName;        
        $from->send("File '{$fileName}' uploaded and processed.");
        flush();

        //cek file
        if (!file_exists($path)) {
            $from->send("File '{$fileName}' not found.");
            return;
        }         

        //mulai proses
        $spreadsheet = IOFactory::load($path);
        $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
        $total_rows = $sheet->getHighestRow() - 1;

        $batchSize = 10;
        $messageBuffer = '';
        for ($i = 2; $i <= $sheet->getHighestRow(); $i++) { 
            if ($i > $total_rows) {
                $messageBuffer .= "Processed all rows.";
                break;
            }
            $messageBuffer .= "Processed row $i\n";
            if ($i % $batchSize === 0) {
                $from->send($messageBuffer);
                $messageBuffer = '';
            }
        }

        //Send any remaining messages in the buffer
        if (!empty($messageBuffer)) {
            $from->send($messageBuffer);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but why will the message be sent after the looping process is complete, what I hope is that even though the looping process is running it can send a message to the client, or maybe it's because the client and server files are different so the code doesn't run perfectly?